# HTTP Error 405, Live Server VSCODE method POST

Tags: php, html, post

Muy buenas, tengo un problema al utilizar el método "POST" en un formulario HTML, ya que al hacer el submit me arroja error http 405.

```
<section id="contacto">
    <div class="container">
        <form action="correo.php" class="contact" method="POST">
            <div class="formulario">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="formulario">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="formulario">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Asunto</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="asunto" name="asunto">
            </div>
            <div class="formulario">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Mensaje</label>
                <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="formulario">
                <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

Quiero que envíe el email que está configurado en "correo.php".

```
<?php
{
$destinatario = 'felipeeduardo.guzman@gmail.com';
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$header = "Enviar desde mi página web";
$mensajeCompleto = $mensaje ."\nAtentamente: ".$nombre;

mail($destinatario, $asunto, $mensaje, $header);
echo "<script>alert('correo enviado exitosamente')</script>";
echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href='../index.html'\",1000)</script>";
}
```

Estoy ejecutando este html con la extensión Live Server de VSCODE.

Soy nuevo en esto, pero necesito ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes por favor proporcionar más detalles del problema, como por ejemplo una captura de pantalla del problema.

Answer (score 1):

el LIVE SERVER  de vscode no admite el método POST, prueba de alojar la web en otro server local que si lo admita como xampp

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).